# Accessing RequestContextHolder and HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() from AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring-MVC application (i.e. I am using the Spring's dispatcher servlet). I am also using Spring Security to authenticate users. Since I use the Spring's dispatcher servlet, I do NOT have to declare

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

in my web.xml in order to be able to use `RequestContextHolder` (if I understand correctly the documentation).

My question refers to my implementation of the interface `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int timeout = 60*60;

        //does work
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout); //60 minutes
        System.out.println("Session timeout of user: " + authentication.getName() + " has been set to: " + timeout + " seconds.");

        /*
        //does not work
        session().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout); //60 minutes
        System.out.println("Session timeout of user: " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + " has been set to: " + timeout + " seconds.");
        */

        //now restore the default work flow (SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler is the default AuthenticationSuccessHandler that Spring uses,
        // see: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#form-login-flow-handling )
        (new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

    public static HttpSession session() {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
    }
}
```

**Could you explain why** in the above mentioned code, `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` and `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` do not work (they do work inside a Controller)?

Thanks!

Comment: Euh, you already have 'RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes' (it's the request method parameter), and you already have the principal (it's the authentication method parameter). Bit pointless question. Btw, the wrapping of the request, to provide it with a principal, is done in SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, which comes after the form-login (and thus after the success handler).

Answer (score 5):

Spring security is filter-based. That is why you need the RequestContextListener defined since the DispatcherServlet will not have been invoked yet when the spring-security stuff happens and the spring request context will not have been set up.

Comment: Thanks. That answers the `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` part. Now I look at the code of `RequestContextListener` but can't see there any `request.getUserPrincipal()`, so where does the `UserPrincipal` get saved on the `request`? It's not automatically saved before entering `onAuthenticationSuccess()` since it's giving me `NullPointerException` within that method. I'm actually asking where in other filter / dispatcher servlet does `UserPrincipal` get saved on the `request`, and is there some listener that will let me read it from the `request` in `onAuthenticationSuccess()`?